# "at" or "by" in conjunction with the past perfect

Tags: prepositions, past-perfect

In the following passage, should "by" or "at" be used?

> Earlier this month, Saudi photographer Osama Al-Habri captured aerial images of Badr Governorate, southwest of the Islamic pilgrimage city of Medina, dressed in white as locals gathered to enjoy the unusual sight.

> Al-Harbi told CNN that winter weather of such intensity in the Badr desert area was a rare phenomenon that had not occurred for years. He described it as a "historic hailstorm."

> The Saudi photographer, who documented the scenes on January 11, said the site was teeming with visitors, many of whom had traveled miles for a glimpse of the frozen landscape.

> **At/By** the time of Al-Harbi's visit, Saudi Arabia's National Center of Meteorology **had forecast** moderate to heavy rain in the Medina region, along with winds, low visibility and hail, according to the Saudi Press Agency.

Comment: Please tell us what you already know about "at/by" before time expressions like "the time of Al-Barbi's visit" so we don't waste our time explaining things you already know.

Answer (score 2):

There is no grammatical reason why one should be better than the other, but **at** makes more sense. On the day the photographer was there, that was the current weather forecast (which had been issued earlier).

**By the time** would imply that, when he visited, some significant development had already taken place. *By the time he arrived, the hail had already melted.*

Comment: How about the following? "At/By the time of the ceremony, the organizer had prepared the gifts for the guests"?

Comment: Well,if the gifts were for presentation at the ceremony, one would hope they _had_ been prepared by the time it started!